# Object does not show when pasted into scene

Tags: objects, scene

As a Blender newbie --Man sometimes it's the stupidest things that get me stumped. I downloaded a skull from blendswap. Changed the material to glass and then copied it, pasted it into a new scene. It shows up in the upper left elements list --but it's NO where in my scene! What am I not getting? Some so simple and yet -- arrrgh.

The file I copied it from is here: http://www.aworkofmarc.com/1/blender/SculptStudio.blend

The file I pasted it into is here:
http://www.aworkofmarc.com/1/blender/Crystal_Rack1.blend

Can someone please look and see what's wrong?

Comment: When the mesh is imported from [another .blend](http://www.blender.org/manual/data_system/linked_libraries.html), it is placed on the same [3D Layer](http://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/layers.html?highlight=layers), where it was placed in the original file. In this case, you should press `Shift`+`2` to see the skull which is located on the 2-nd layer.

Comment: Thank you! And sorry for such a dummy question but I'm learning this as I go, obviously there's a LOT of blind spots.

Comment: @MrZak can you write an answer? (It would help move this out of the unanswered questions list)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the mesh is imported from [another blend](http://www.blender.org/manual/data_system/linked_libraries.html), - either linked or appended, it is placed on the same [3D Layer](http://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/layers.html?highlight=layers) where it was in the original file.

To see whether there is something on any layer, look at the layers tab:

[image]

Layer 1 is selected, while both - 1-st and 2-nd have dot in the middle of the small rectangle.

This dot is orange - currently active object is located on that layer.

This dot is grey - there is/are some objects on that layer.

[To show the mesh located on another layer](http://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/layers.html?highlight=layers#viewing-layers), either <kbd>Shift</kbd> click on that rectangle, or press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + number of adjacent layer (in this case 2-nd). The mesh will be shown.

[image]